# Did a group meditation in Delhi (1988-1990) influence the world peace?

Tags: war, meditation

Snippets from the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8SYlV3ihl4 at https://www.unify.org/

The concept of **morphic resonance** was widely promoted by banning the TEDx talk by Rupert Sheldrake: https://blog.ted.com/the-debate-about-rupert-sheldrakes-talk/

Just wondering where to find more information about the group meditation in Delhi and the world peace?

[image]

Text:

> Between 1988 - 1990, a group of 8,000 meditators in Delhi focused on World Peace

[image]

Text:

> During this time, nearly every major conflict in the world peacefully resolved

- Is it true that meditators gathered in Delhi during that period ?
- Did most on-going world conflicts resolved between 1988 and 1990 ?
- If both previous answers are 'yes', can any relation be established between both events ?

Comment: Hello, and congrats on your first question here! Skeptics [is for challenging notable claims](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), not for asking where you can find information on a subject. If your reword your question to ask whether the claims in the linked image are true and prove that a large number of people believe the claims, then it would be an on-topic question here. Otherwise, your question may be [closed](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as off-topic.

Comment: Additionally, a note: Rupert Sheldrake's talk was at a TEDx conference, not a TED conference.

Comment: Michael, You've asked a few questions that haven't been well received. Please read the [welcome page](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) to understand who we are better. There are several extraordinary claims in this video - if you wanted to quote one of them, we could address whether it is true.

Comment: For example: "Did 8000 people in Dehli focus their meditations on World Peace between 1998 and 1990?"

Comment: I tried to edit the question to make it more factual. Anyway, is wonder how this video address the major wars that *started* in 1989-90, like the Gulf war or the civil wars in Rwanda, Mali or the Philippines...

Comment: ... and US invasion of Panama, btw : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Panama

Comment: If this video/claim was made after 1990, it smells like the [Texas shapshooter fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_sharpshooter_fallacy): set the goals after the facts. It can still be investigated of course, but why not e.g. 1988-1992?

Comment: The idea that the talk in question was "banned", or that that banning led to it being "widely promoted" are themselves potentially nontrivial claims.  You could run them off of semantics, I suppose, but doing so to both at the same time involves twisting the language to the point of near-meaninglessness.

Comment: The talk was banned. Banning leads to "widely promoted", as with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect - nontrivial but kind of obvious in my version of reality.